# Looping array and displaying text

Tags: jquery

I have the following array

```
var arr = ['abc', 'efg', 'igj', 'feeu', 'fee'];
```

I want to do the following two tasks:

Loop through this array and display the text in a div called DIVCont one by one in a continuous manner and a cycle. There should be a gap of two seconds for each word.

My second requirement is to be able to click on the div called DIVClick to display the next word in the array. Each click will fetch the next word in a cycle.

I do not want to use any extra plugin for this.

Comment: why don't you want to use any extra plugins?  You will probably need to use a timer for doing transitions so you can either try hand-coding one in javascript or use the JQuery timer plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var arr = ['abc', 'efg', 'igj', 'feeu', 'fee'];
var index = arr.length;

$(function() {
    $('div#DIVClick').click(updateDiv);
    setInterval(updateDiv, 2000);
});

function updateDiv() {
    $('div#DIVCont').html(arr[(index++) % arr.length]);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Will this behave correctly when (say) I click on it at 3 seconds? It will have changed at 2 seconds, and then when I clicked on it at 3 seconds. Will the next change be at 4 or 5 seconds? I believe 5 is what the OP would like.

Comment: Thanks Does this loop? After the array reaches end, I want it to start again from beginning like a loop.

Comment: Yes it does loop, and yes it will start again from the beginning when it reaches the end, but I think the time you wasted posting questions you could have created an HTML page and tested the code yourself and see if it fits your needs.